# Multiple expression in LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want combine my expression built in runtime (CustomExpression) with ordinary select clausule. Is there any way in C# to do this without manually building whole expression?

```
var dto = iqueryable.Select(d => new DTO() 
{
     X = d.X,
     Y = d.Y,
     Z = CustomExpression
 }
```

Where `CustomExpression` is something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<EntityTypeFromIQueryable, string>> CustomExpression() {
    get {
        // there is manually built expression like this:
        return x => x.Blah
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this code? is it working? or you getting any errors

Comment: No, you can not compile this code. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<entity,string>>' to 'string'

Comment: Imagine "Z" property is type string, but CustomExpression is Expression wich after compile return string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do anything of sorts using normal LINQ. You could try Dynamic LIQN instead.

Comment: I don't think you can do it like this, because you can not assign expression to string type, so it will not work

Comment: I know this will not work. But you can do this by manualy building whole expression ( dynamicly in code). But i am to lazy to this, so i am searching for some elegant solution

Comment: I have written answer for the same, it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert some kind of compilable placeholder (like an *Extension Method*) into your expression first. Then, at runtime, you can modify the expression using an *Expression Visitor* to replace your "placeholder" with the actual lambda expression. Since your actual expression uses different *Parameters* (`d` vs. `x`) you have to replace them with those of the "original" expression.

In fact, i'm playing around with such scenarios within [this project](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq), where i've tried to abstract this kind of expression plumbing. Your "combine" would then look like that:

```
var dto = iqueryable.ToInjectable().Select(d => new DTO() 
{
    X = d.X,
    Y = d.Y,
    Z = d.CustomExpression()
} 

public static class CustomExpressions
{
    [InjectLambda]
    public static string CustomExpression(this EntityTypeFromIQueryable value)
    {
        // this function is just a placeholder
        // you can implement it for non LINQ use too...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<EntityTypeFromIQueryable, string>> CustomExpression()
    {
        return x => x.Blah
    }
}
```

The call `ToInjectable()` creates a lightweight proxy around the original *Queryable* to modify the expression before execution as described. The attribute `InjectLambda` marks the "placeholder" as "inject lambda here". By convention the actual expression returned by `ToInjectable()` gets inserted at the desired position.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in following way:

```
 static void MultipleExpressionInSelectStatement()
    {
        List<person> p = new List<person>();
        p.Add(new person() { name = "AB", age = 18 });
        p.Add(new person() { name = "CD", age = 45 });
        var dto = p.Select(d => new person()
        {
            name=d.name,
            age=p.Select(ListExtensions.CustomExpression()).ElementAt(0)
        });
    }

//customExpression

 public static class ListExtensions
{


    public static Func<person, int> CustomExpression()
    {
        return x => x.age;
    }
}

//Person Object

 public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is Func, not Expression